# Oh My Zsh - git plugin alises ggp (git push origin $(current_branch)) vs. ggpush (git push origin "$(git_current_branch)")

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In Oh My Zsh git plugin documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git), among the listed aliases commands there are the following:

| Alias | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ggp | git push origin $(current_branch) |
| ggpush | git push origin "$(git_current_branch)" |
| ggl | git pull origin $(current_branch) |
| ggpull | git pull origin "$(git_current_branch)" |

What is the difference between `$(current_branch)` and `"$(git_current_branch)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, `current_branch` is a compatibility alias for `git_current_branch`. See [the code](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/0ab87c26c17171ae6162ff379a0c704fa57dff2e/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh#L9).